AWS IVS web broadcast `requestRTCStats` returns `undefined`
I'm trying to monitor the stream metrics like encodekbps and other data available through requestRTCStats. However, when I invoke const report = await stream.requestRTCStats() I get that report === undefined.
According to the code I get on Chrome developer tools I see this happens when publish:
this.publish = t=>{
  this.logger.debug({
    msg: "publish"
  }),
  t.forEach((t=>{
    t && (this.setupStreamListener(t),
    t.streamType === Ve.AUDIO ? (this.audioStream = t,
      this.audioMuted = !t.mediaStreamTrack.enabled,
      this.info.audioMuted = this.audioMuted) : t.streamType === Ve.VIDEO && (this.videoStream = t,
        this.videoStopped = !t.mediaStreamTrack.enabled,
        this.info.videoStopped = this.videoStopped),
        t.setGetStats(this.publication.requestRTCStats))
      })),
      this.connection.emitStageState(this.audioMuted, this.videoStopped);
      const e = t.map((t=>this.toMediaTrackWithConfig(t)));
        this.publication.start(e)
},

That's minimised code from amazon-ivs-web-broadcast package.
That happens after I:
const stage = new Stage(token, strategy);
// some logic
await stage.join();

I get my video and audio streamed just fine, but for some reason I'm not able to requestRTCStats, any ideas?
EDIT 1 - Solution: instead of tracking the streams separately, you should listen for the implemented streams available in the StageEvents.STAGE_PARTICIPANT_STREAMS_ADDED handler like:
const stage = new Stage(token, strategy);

stage.on(StageEvents.STAGE_PARTICIPANT_STREAMS_ADDED, async (participant, streams) => {
  // in here you can be sure `requestRTCStats` is not returning `undefined`
  for(const stream of streams) {
    const rtcReport = await stream.requestRTCStats()
  }
});

await stage.join();

